# Not receiving separate values on the server-side client-server TCP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server, buffer

I have a problem with receiving the correct values on the server-side of my client-server program.

**header file included in both server and client:**

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 1024
#define ARR_LEN 3
```

**client:**

```
int uids[ARR_LEN] = {1994, 2423, 1222};
unsigned int uidlen = 0;
char uidbuffer[CHUNK_SIZE] = {0};

for(int i = 0; i < ARLL; i++)
{
    uidlen = strlen(uids[i])+1;
    snprintf(uidbuffer, uidlen, "%s", uids[i]);

    if(send(socket, uidbuffer, strlen(uidbuffer), 0) < 0)
        DIE("Write Error");
    if(recv(socket, uidbuffer, sizeof(uidbuffer), 0) < 0)
        DIE("Acknowledge Error");

    memset(uidbuffer, 0, sizeof(uidbuffer));
}
```

**server:**

```
char uid_buff[CHUNK_SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; i++)
{
    memset(uid_buff, 0, sizeof(uid_buff));
    // receiving the UID and storing it directly
    if(recv(client_sock, uid_buff, sizeof(uid_buff), 0) < 0)
        DIE("Receive Error");

    printf("buffer content: %s\n", uid_buff);
    uid_str = uid_buff;

    uids[i] = (uid_t)strtol(uid_str, (char **)NULL, 10);

    if(send(client_sock, uid_buff, sizeof(uid_buff), 0) < 0)
        DIE("Acknowledge Error");
}
```

These are only parts of my program. I tried to only include the relevant parts. The output is this:

```
buffer content: 1994
buffer content: 24231222
buffer content:
```

While I want it to be:

```
buffer content: 1994
buffer content: 2423
buffer content: 1222
```

What could be the problem? I know that it's not so easy and that server–client communication is carried out in a stream of bytes rather than messages, but I want to mimmic that functionality by acknowledging every received "message". Could you please clue me what to do? I'm getting desperate.

Comment: does anyone know an answer to this? this interests me very much

Comment: You're checking your send() and recv() calls for negative values only.  There are other cases you need to check for as well -- specifically you should check to see if recv() returned 0 (in which case the TCP connection was closed), and also if send() or recv() returned a value that is greater than zero but less than the number of bytes you specified (in which case only the first part of your data-buffer was read-by-send(), or written-to-by-recv(), and you would need to loop to transfer the rest of the bytes in the array)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner could you please propose a specific solution? If I check for `> 0`, I want to store those bytes to the same buffer? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The client code is bogus: `uids` is undefined and used inconsistently, same for `buffer`.

Comment: @chqrlie I forgot to include that. Let me edit.

Comment: Your code cannot compile as written: `strlen(uids[i])` is meaningless for `int uids[]`

Comment: Please do not attempt to destroy your question after you have an answer.  I've rolled back your edit that removed the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually I don't have an answer.

Comment: You have two answers.  You may not have understood them, but you do have two answers.  The key points are that you have to determine the message boundaries yourself, which means you need a protocol of some sort for determining when a message is complete.  You might use a TLV (type, length, value) scheme, or you might use an end marker scheme (newline or null byte), or you might use some other system.  But the receiver must be able to tell where the message boundaries are, which means the sender must tell it.  Sometimes — maybe in your example — the messages are all a fixed size; that's easy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm currently sending strings exclusively, all of those have null bytes at the end, right? So I should only check for a null byte in a receiving loop and break upon reaching it?

Comment: As long as your sending code includes the null byte, and as long a null byte is never part of the data (only an end marker), then yes; you can read up to the null byte. You might consider buffering the input; reading what's available, and passing back just the material up to the first null (if there is a null), leaving anything after the first null around to be returned by the next reading operation. If there isn't a null available after the first read operation, you'll need to try reading some more until the null arrives, or you get bored and time out, or you detect the connection is closed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your help, you have been very helpful so far. I just don't know how should I read what I received by bytes – should I do `recv(socket, buffer, 1, 0)` and check the contents of the buffer?

Comment: That is an option, but not a very good one.  You are not buffering at all, and single-byte I/O is slower than multi-byte I/O because you make many more system calls.  I recommend something along the lines of `char buffer[1024]; int nbytes = recv(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` to read up to 1 KiB of data, and then recording how much was received (`nbytes`) and returning the first section of what was received appropriately — and leaving behind a record of what has been received but not returned. You might end up needing your own structure analogous to a `FILE *` to record this information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But where's the null terminator checking here? Do I `printf("%s", buffer[nbytes]);`? I'm having trouble understanding that.

Comment: @user3710031: you might need smth like readall in my answer. recv may receive fewer bytes

Comment: @Giorgi the only difference from sendall would be the function `recv` instead of `send`?

Comment: The code in `recv()` doesn't do the null detection; you have to do that in code you write on top of the `recv()` call.  So, after `recv()` returns you 31 bytes, you scan through the data and find that there's a null byte at offset 9, so you return that section as the first message, then you find there's another null byte at offset 20, so you return the section from 10..20; then you find another null byte at offset 30, so you return the section form 21..30.  That's the easy case. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  It could be that there is no null byte at offset 30 (the 31st byte).  In that case, you need to move byte offset 21-30 to the beginning of the buffer and read more data at the end, repeating until you come across a null byte or decide there is a protocol error (you've read 1024 bytes but the longest valid request is 128 bytes) or something similar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why would there be so many null bytes? That would be only if I send the whole thing in one `send`, right? Because I'm doing multiple receives and sends now. So should I just do one send and one receive and "parse" the messages appropriately?

Comment: @user3710031: Yes, I think that's the only difference. Do like this "message/0othermessage/0stillothermessage/0". Here are three messages, send this whole array to server like this: first send length (39) of the whole array then the array. Use the read all to receive first the length - then the array itself. then do the parsing

Comment: Yes, you can send it all in one message if you want; your options are legion.  The important thing is that messages can be sub-divided on the network, so just because you send 1024 bytes in a single request doesn't mean you'll get a single 1024 buffer full in a single receive request; you might get 300, 300, 300 and 124 bytes, for example.  If you don't know how long the message was, you won't know when you've reached the end.  That's why end markers, or lengths, are used in protocols: here is a byte buffer of length 1024 bytes; here are 1024 bytes of data.  The receiver knows what to expect.

Comment: @Giorgi Could you maybe include a real-world example in your answer? That would probably help me understand the most.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm beginning to understand, thanks. I'm trying to implement it now. Should I still include the acknowledgments?

Comment: @user3710031: I gave you some example

Comment: @Giorgi great, I'll have a look

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added an example of what I'm trying now. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a protocol.
For example, you define that each message in your application has following format:

```
xx | message
```

this means first two bytes (mind the endianness) you receive indicate the length of the message that follows. Now you should first receive first two bytes - check the length - and then receive exactly that number of bytes. After that you know you have successfully received that message. And then you can proceed to other messages (which could/should have similar format: length + message itself).

Example:
Say you want to send three messages:

```
char s1[]="message1";
char s2[]="message2";
char s3[]="message3";

//You do this(client side):

int x1 = strlen(s1); // length of message1
int intsize = 4; // just size of integer -we'll need in next call

sendall(socket, &x1, &intsize); // send length of first message
sendall(socket, s1, &x1); // Now send the message

//On server:
int x = 0;
int y = 4; //size of integer most probably
receiveall(socket,&x,&y);//get length first; y=4 because that is size of integer
receiveall(socket, buffer, &x); // now we know how many bytes to expect - x - so request that number of bytes only
```

you can repeat this logic for other messages too.

Finally, you want to use such functions ([here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#sendall)) instead of `send` and `receive` (because send and receive might not send/receive the number of bytes you tell it to):

```
int sendall(int s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to send
    int n;

    while(total < *len) {
        n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total; // return number actually sent here

    return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

you will need a similar `receiveall` function.

Answer (score 1):

You do not show the code that establishes the connection.

If you are using UDP sockets, each message is stand alone, you will receive a separate message for each message sent, but not necessarily in the same order.

If you are using TCP or Unix sockets, data may be received in chunks of different sizes than those used for sending.  Only the sequence of bytes is preserved, not the chunk sizes.  You need to specify a protocol: unless you specify a fixed number of bytes per message, you need to send some sort of separator to allow the server to tell where each message ends.

Comment: Which part of connection handling do you need?

Comment: Just specify the type of socket connection.  But you will need to make a choice of communication protocol no matter what type of connection.

Comment: No, not needed, read my answer: you need to send some kind of delimiter (such as '\n') and bufferize received bytes in the server until you see that delimiter.